# how to create convert an excel to documents4j pdf and download this in horizontal format

Tags: java, documents4j

Hello I have a problem with Documents4j, the file is being converted, but I see the PDF and Excel is cut into the PDF, I have to create a PDF and show excel on the full PDF without cutting.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. You could implement your own `IConverter` and take the current MS Excel converter as a blueprint. The converter uses the VBS API to convert the documents, it probably has a parameter for such transformations.

Comment: yes sir, i did implement Itext use rectangular and other parameters. Thank you very much very much for replying